# customer id error while trying to work with google ads API. what input customer id takes? and why iam getting this error message?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm trying to work with google ads API I got all the authentication in place on yaml file. and I'm ready to start requesting info from the Google API

I downloaded the generate_keyword_ideas.py file from google GitHub
this is the file here:
https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-python/blob/ee2c059498d5679a0d1d9011f3795324439fad7c/examples/planning/generate_keyword_ideas.py

in short the file function takes all these inputs

```
def main(
client, customer_id, location_ids, language_id, keyword_texts, page_url
```

)

when i run the main file i get this error message:

```
usage: main.py [-h] -c CUSTOMER_ID [-k KEYWORD_TEXTS [KEYWORD_TEXTS ...]]
           [-l LOCATION_IDS [LOCATION_IDS ...]] [-i LANGUAGE_ID]
           [-p PAGE_URL]
main.py: error: the following arguments are required: -c/--customer_id
```

I don't know what kind of input customer_id takes, coz I got my 10 digits id from google ads and I thought that's what it is but its not, and also what is -c? and how can I fill both of them?, iv been trying for a long time and nothing is working .. please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

-c is the command line flag to indicate that what's coming next is the customer ID.

The customer ID for authentication is confusing. I had a hard time with it too. Try using the MCC/Manager account ID (another 10 digit number) without any dashes.

I would also consider starting with something a little more simple. In the example, try the list accessible customers one and go from there. You'll get a feel for what's what.